# Regex: Optional special characters

Tags: regex

I have a regex which has the following rules:

```
+ Must contain lower case letters
+ Must contain upper case letters
+ Must contain a number
+ Must contain a (defined)special character
+ At least 8 chars
```

This works and my regex looks like this:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[~@#\$%\^&\*_\-\+=`|{}:;!\.\?\"()\[\]]).{8,25})
```

Now I want to change that regex in only one single thing:
The special characters should still be possible (and only those I allow), but should be optional (not required anymore) anywhere in the string.
So the new rule would be

```
+ MAY contain (defined) special characters
```

What do I have to change to achieve this?

Examples:

```
NicePassw0rd - NOT OK now, should be
NicePassw0rd%% - OK now (and still should be)
NicePassword - NOT OK now and shouldnt
```

You can test my regex there: https://regex101.com/r/qN5dN0/1

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Remove `(?=.*[~@#\$%\^&\*_\-\+=\`|{}:;!\.\?\"()\[\]])`. Add anchors `^` and `$` on both ends of the pattern. Or if you want to disallow other special characters, move to the consuming part with letters and digits: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\w~@#$%^&*+=\`|{}:;!.?\"()\[\]-]{8,25}$`

Comment: Try this `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,25})` Removing the following parantheses content from your current regex should work `(?=.*[~@#\$%\^&\*_\-\+=`|{}:;!\.\?\"()\[\]])`

Comment: Does [my above regex](https://regex101.com/r/qN5dN0/2) work for you? Also, what is the regex flavor? Is it really PCRE?

Comment: Yes. Looks fine. Thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must add anchors `^` and `$` on both ends of the pattern to really enable length checking. If you want to disallow other special characters, move `` ~@#$%^&*+=`|{}:;!.?\"()\[\]- `` to the consuming part with letters and digits (note that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is the same as `\w` if you are using PCRE without `/u` flag):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\w~@#$%^&*+=`|{}:;!.?\"()\[\]-]{8,25}$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN5dN0/2)

Here is what it does:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*\d)` - require at least one digit
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - require at least a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - require at least 1 ASCII uppercase letter
- `` [\w~@#$%^&*+=`|{}:;!.?\"()\[\]-]{8,25} `` - match (=consume) 8 to 25 only symbols that are either alphanumeric, or `_`, or all those inside the character class
- `$` - end of string

A more efficient would be a regex based on [*contrast principle*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) within lookaheads when we check for 0 or more characters other than those we need to check for presence and then the required symbol. See a corrected regex containing `(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])`:

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[\w~@#$%^&*+=`|{}:;!.?\"()\[\]-]{8,25}$
```